# React-native Unable to show any content on my app.js screen

Tags: react-native

I can't seem to figure out what seems to be the issue.  I am getting a render error, "Could'nt find a 'component'; get component or children prop for the screen dashboard.  This can happen if you passed 'undefined'.  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined.

````
My code in App.js is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import {
    MainLayout
} from "./screens";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}
                initialRouteName={'Dashboard'}
            >
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Dashboard"
                    component={MainLayout}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default App

```

My code in /screens/Dashboard/MainLayout is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text
} from 'react-native';

const MainLayout = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>MainLayout</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default MainLayout;

```
````

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting `MainLayout` as default so import it without `{ }`. You can import default component with any name but non default components with exact name inside `{ }`.

Change your import in **`App.js`** like below ( It seems that you also not given full path)

```
... // rest of imports

import MainLayout from "./screens/Dashboard/MainLayout";

... // rest of codes
```

[Click here to know more about Importing and Exporting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-importing-exporting/)